# Windows Phone Image Source binding to listbox selected item

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `listbox` of images. And a image control. When I select an image in `listbox` that image should be shown in image control. But its not happening.

Here is my xaml:

```
ScrollViewer x:Name="Sc" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="550" >

           <ListBox Name="imageList" Height="556" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" SelectionChanged="imageList_SelectionChanged">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                          <Image Source="{Binding Imgs}" Width="100" Height="100"/>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>



                <Image x:Name="Image1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="133,28,5,29" Source="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=imageList}"/>
```

Comment: Which is your the ItemSource of the ListBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code I don't know which is the `ItemSource` of your `ListBox` element and which is the type of the items, but looking to the `ItemTemplate` I deduce that each element of the ListBox has a property called `Imgs`, pointing to the source of the images.

In that case, the binding of the Source property of your `Image1` element, should point to the `Imgs` property of the `SelectedItem`:

```xml
<Image x:Name="Image1" Source="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Imgs, ElementName=imageList}" Stretch="Fill" Margin="133,28,5,29" />
```

Comment: hey ander give me ur contact(anything that i can contact u).